# How Can I Host Multiple Websites Under One Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I've followed this guide to do this but I'm having no luck inspite of my incessant Googling. Any advice would be supremely appreciated.

https://nouveauframework.org/blog/vhosts-running-multiple-sites-on-a-single-aws-ec2-instance/

I've setup Hosted Zones for the respective domains I wish to host. I've linked them to my instance via A records pointing to the instance IP, as well as adding the new nameserver records to the domains hosted on Namecheap. Furthermore I've created a vhosts folder on my server and edited the httpd.conf file with the respective VirtualHost details and changes needed.

The default Apache page is loading when I visit my respective website domains but the actual website pages themselves are not loading.

How can I fix this?

I'm getting this error when restarting HTTPD

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

The domain names in questions alphagleam.co.uk and conflictzonenorthwest.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your `httpd.conf` file and make sure to include

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

once done make sure to restart apache and it should be ok